# I have a question about changing the data frame type

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, eval

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num':['9','','3','7','11']})
col_nm = 'num'
print(df)

  num
0   9
1    
2   3
3   7
4  11
```

I succeeded with help here.

```
string = "np.where(num >= 5 , 5,num) "
df[col_nm] = pd.to_numeric(df[col_nm],errors='coerce')
string= string.replace(col_nm,"df['"+col_nm+"']")
df[col_nm] = eval(string)
print(df)

   num
0  5.0
1  NaN
2  3.0
3  5.0
4  5.0
```

but, pd.to_numeric(downcast = 'integer') not worked...
I want to change it back to its original state.

```
   num                num
0  5.0             0    5
1  NaN             1    
2  3.0        =>   2    3   
3  5.0             3    5
4  5.0             4    5
```

Comment: `NaN` in your column will always downcasts your column to float. You can use `'Int64'` dtype for nullable integers. Otherwise you need to resolve to `str/object` dtype as in your original data.

Comment: why are you using `eval` for a df operation?

Comment: Because there's a string in the Oracle db to process the columns.